# Instagram API to fetch self data returning empty response

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying Instagram api to fetch followers list.
I have generated client id, secret and access token.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=7295104237.9baac5e.680b2694931642a18e3758b3cd8aff55
```

This API works properly. It shows follows count as 2.

But when I run below API with same access token, It does not return any data of the username, etc:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?access_token=7295104237.9baac5e.680b2694931642a18e3758b3cd8aff55
```

Please could anyone help me with this. I've been searching for this since hours now.

Answer (score 2):

You may not have access to theses actions.

Go to the https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Click the settings icon.
Find your api account and click Manage, after that click Permission. You'll see there about your api information.

Approved - featured - which you can use

N/A - featured - which you cannot use

Comment: Yes, all permissions are N/A. How to make it to approved?

Comment: @Mamta if all permissions is N/A, you have no authorized to use api. Go to the https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/manage and click to register client and follow the guide. But you must show your demo project for accepting it by Instagram. If my post helped you, please vote it.

Comment: My app is in development mode. This is what instagram site mentions : "Every new app created on the Instagram Platform starts in Sandbox mode. Apps in this mode can use any API endpoint but are restricted to a limited number of users and media. This is great for developing and testing your app."
How to get permissions for it?

Comment: Go to the permissions and click the start a permission. After you must follow the guide.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found an answer to this!

My app is in sandbox mode. Until one of your followers/someone you follow doesn't become your sandbox users, their data will not be listed by the followers/followed-by API, or any other API for that matter.

This is because this info is considered as public_content and will only completely accessible after app is live and completely given permission for by Instagram.

So.. Just add one of your followers/someone you follow to your sandbox users! And your sorted!!